# Remain on the product page with an upsell add to cart button

Tags: magento-1.9, product, addtocart

I have added an "Add to Cart" button for the upsell items on the product view page, using the following code:

```
<button type="button" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_link) ?>')">
  <?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>
</button>
```

The problem is that when adding the product to the cart it then redirects to the home page. I have the `After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart` option set to `No` in the checkout configuration.

How do I get it to stay on the same page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My particular issue was that I was using varnish and magento was adding port 8080 to the return url which produced an error as it seemed like an external url.

My quick fix was to add `if ( $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 8080 ) { $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] = 80; }` right before `Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);` in index.php.

Not a permanent solution but it did the trick.

Answer (score 4):

Magento have a function *`_goBack()`* at `Mage_Checkout_CartController`,which is give us the facility to redirect  user at any page after successfully Cart from addAction  by add an extra parameter( `return_url`) with add to cart url.

> ```
> protected function _goBack()
>     {
>         $returnUrl = $this->getRequest()->getParam('return_url');
>       /* Check have value of return_url  */
>         if ($returnUrl) {
>
>             if (!$this->_isUrlInternal($returnUrl)) {
>                 throw new Mage_Exception('External urls redirect to "' . $returnUrl . '" denied!');
>             }
>
>             $this->_getSession()->getMessages(true);
>       /* then redirect to this page */
>             $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($returnUrl);
> ```

At _goBack magento have check,current Action have any value for  `return_url` param.If have then it  redirect to customer to that page.

For this case,you need  send a extra parameter `return_url`  with add to cart url.

Currently,you getting cart url from  `$this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_link)` and parent current page url  as `return_url` value

```
<button type="button" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_link).'?return_url= '.Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl() ?>')">
  <?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>
</button
```

Comment: Amit Bera@ Go admin side :System -> Checkout -> After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart option set to Yes then is working fine?

Comment: Hey @Amit Bera. The issue was with my varnish configuration, it was adding the port 8080 to the return urls. Thank you showing me how that works, I never knew about return_url/_goback and I'm sure it will prove useful in the future.

Answer (score 3):

When you add a product to the cart if 'redirect to shopping cart' is disable the controller action tries to:

1. Find a "uenc" paramenter (is a hash with the url for redirect to)
2. Get the referer url (from the request)
3. If 1 and 2 fails then redirects to the home

Mage_Checkout_Helper_Cart::getAddUrl() accept an array as second parameter so when you are adding products outside the product view page, you can add the uenc parameter for the current url like that:

```
$currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
$uenc = Mage::helper('core/url')->urlEncode($currentUrl);
// Note that you can use any url you want.
... 
$this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_link, array('uenc'=> $uenc))
...
```

EDIT: Try this (Using the same concept as @AmitBera) but without concatenation:

```
$currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();

... 
$this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_link, array('return_url'=> $currentUrl))
...
```

Comment: Hi @MauroNigrele. Thanks for the info mate, unfortunately this still redirects to the home page, I was adding them to cart from the product page view, not outside of it.(I've made that clearer in my original post) Thank you for going through the logic of how it works, that is really useful.

Comment: Hi @MaruoNigrele. The issue was with my varnish configuration, it was adding the port 8080 to the return urls. Thanks again for that info, it's good to know more about how that works.

Comment: cool! remember to always try new features with and without cache(s) specially varnish and fpc.

Comment: I have all the other cache's disabled but naively thought varnish wouldn't effect this. Thank you for your time mate.

Answer (score 1):

just try this

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_link) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
```

Comment: Hi @Adbul. Unfortunately this also redirects to the home page after adding the product to the cart.

Comment: It is working fine. Pls clear magento Cache  and try again

Comment: Hi @Abdul. I don't have the cache enabled at all, that's not the issue.

Comment: function getAddToCartUrl(); is working base on admin side setting

Comment: After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart option set to Yes then redirect cart page & No then redirect same page

Comment: Hi @Abdul. The issue was with my varnish configuration, it was adding the port 8080 to the return urls. Thank you for your help.

Comment: if help full my ans pls vote me :)